# Pin a UISegmentedControl underneath UINavigationBar in a UITableView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

How do I pin a UISegmentedControl underneath a UINavigationBar with a UITableView?

```
UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc]initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"One", @"Two", nil]]; 
[segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentedControlHasChangedValue:)     forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = segmentedControl;
```

I've set up this UISegmentedControl like this so far, however, it scrolls with the rest of the UITableView content.

Comment: Is this in a UITableViewController?

Comment: Yes the segmented control is in a uitableviewcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use segmentedControl as your section header view.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc]initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"One", @"Two", nil]];
    [segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentedControlHasChangedValue:)     forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    return segmentedControl ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
NSArray *keyWordsList; 

 segmentControl = [[[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:keyWordsList] autorelease];
    [segmentControl setSegmentedControlStyle:UISegmentedControlStyleBar];

    [segmentControl setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 47, 300, 30)];
    [segmentControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [segmentControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentColorAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    [segmentControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:0];
    segmentControl.tag = 2;
    //[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:segmentControl];
    [self.view addSubview:segmentControl];
    segmentControl.hidden =YES;


    [segmentControl setTag:kTagFirst];
```

- kTagFirst provide value